# Solution compiles but does not run on debug. The error appears part English part Spanish

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, sql-server-ce

I am posting this here because on the web I'd only found is how to fix this if you are running on x64 or web.config related stuff, but this is desktop and on a 32bits pc.

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Error while trying to run project: Unable
>   to start debugging.
>
> El objeto invocado ha desconectado de sus clientes.

Translation:

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

This is the weird error I get when I'm trying to compile my project

These are the things I'm working with:

- A tiny WinForms Solution
- C# VS2008 3.5Fwk
- SQL.CE
- On a dying Atom x86

Comment: Can you post your code so we can know what to look for? As for the Spanish part, it says the Object invocated has disconnected from its clients, if that can help you narrow it down.

Comment: @Adam I'll do that once I get home. For the spanish part I know what it means since Spanish is my native language... however, despite knowing this and assuming that the problem comes from the database connection or around there, I'll post that code. A pity that doesn't even tell what project of the solution is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try closing the Visual Studio, kill all associated processes and start it again. It worked perfectly for me. Thanks